# Restlet: persistent connection

Tags: restlet, keep-alive, httpconnection, persistent-connection

I am trying to create a Restlet server that will handle long sessions with its clients. So after handling the first request i want to be able to keep the current http connection open and save it in a list of connections. Is this possible?
 I have seen the documentation of Restlet 2.1 but I haven't found any examples of it.

Answer (score 1):

Persistent connections are part of the HTTP 1.1 specification and supported by the Restlet HTTP server connectors, including the internal one, the Jetty and Simple extensions.

See this Javadocs page for the internal connector for example:
http://www.restlet.org/documentation/snapshot/jee/engine/org/restlet/engine/connector/ConnectionHelper.html